# Two buttons(hyperlink, submit) not the same size after apply stylesheet

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have two buttons, the first as `<a>` tag, and the second as `<input type="submit">`.
I want to make the both like some.

The following is screenShot on `firefox`
[image]

Also the following is screenShot on `IE7`
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginForm">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="sbmtLogin" value="Sign in" /> 
        <a href="register.php">Sign up</a> 
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div#loginForm {
    width:270px;
    max-width:270px;
    margin:100px auto;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#8de3fd;
}
div#loginForm input[type=text], div#loginForm input[type=password] {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    width:150px;
    margin:3px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#5b5b5b;
}
div#loginForm label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:70px;
}
div#loginForm input[type=submit] {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    width:50%;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    color:#5b5b5b;
    font: bold 16px arila;
}
div#loginForm a {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    color:#5b5b5b;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: bold 16px arila;
}
```

You can see also [JsFiddle online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking0/JabVj/)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `display:inline-block` to your `<a>` tag. This is just a float issue. Your anchor tag does not have any float.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried to use `display:inline-block` but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes ie wont work some codes correctly...so that time we should  use conditional stylesheets...Here u can use a new stylesheet that include in `<head>` with conditional code like this

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

you can specify your class property whatever you want....it reflect ie7 only...

you can check more here : http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

OR

you can use ie syntax hack..it is so simple and no more stylesheets use for in a site...

```
.class {

    background: gray; /* standard */    
    background: pink\9; /* IE 8 and below */    
    *background: green; /* IE 7 and below */    
    _background: blue; /* IE 6 */

}
```

ie syntax hack : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Hope this help you....

Comment: You're right about the problem that is IE7. However, I can't upvote. The second solution is a horrible, horrible hack that should have been taken out and shot long ago.

Comment: I'm using both solution...I haven't faced no more problems till now...anyway you do as wish ...